# Reading UTF8 chars using innerHTML returns 0xfffd for all chars

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

I'm reading an HTML document that contains UTF-8 chars but when I access the **`innerHTML`** of the document, all the "bad" chars show up as `0xfffd`. I've tried it in all the major browsers and it behaves the same way. When I `alert()` the `innerHTML` it shows those chars as a *"diamond with a ? mark"*.

Surprisingly the following works perfectly, correctly displaying the UTF-8 char in the alert box, so its not `alert()` is malfunctioning.

```
alert("Doppelg\u00e4nger!");
```

Why can't I access the UTF-8 chars using **`innerHTML`**? Or is there another way to access them in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check if the document header contains.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

You can also read out the meta-tags with javascript:

```
var metaTags = document.getElementsByTagName("META");
```

If it does, this is the explanation of the behavior. You can try changing utf-8 to ISO-8859-1:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Better is to htmlEncode all extended characters in your HTML. Like this:

```
function encodeHTML(str){
 var aStr = str.split(''),
     i = aStr.length,
     aRet = [];

   while (--i) {
    var iC = aStr[i].charCodeAt();
    if (iC < 65 || iC > 127 || (iC>90 && iC<97)) {
      aRet.push('&#'+iC+';');
    } else {
      aRet.push(aStr[i]);
    }
  }
 return aRet.reverse().join('');
}
```

Mind you, this function will encode everything that is not [a-zA-Z]. This function will encode Doppelgänger in Doppelg&#228;nger for example.

Comment: Pretty cool. Anyways I found that the problem was with the HTML page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is the page sent with a UTF-8 charset?
`.innerHTML` has never given me any trouble with UTF-8.

Comment: And just how do you debug it? I'm reading the innerHTML from within a frame, if that causes any trouble.

Comment: You can either look at the headers or the page properties - what browser are you using?