# Testing for special characters JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have this HTML element:

```
<td>&mdash;</td>
```

When parsed by browsers, `&mdash;` is converted to an actual em-dash, like so:

```
<td>—</td>
```

How can I test for `&mdash;` without using other characters in my JavaScript code?

```
console.log(elem.innerHTML == "&mdash;"); // false
console.log(elem.textContent == "&mdash;"); // false
console.log(elem.innerHTML == "—"); // true
console.log(elem.textContent == "—"); // true
```

Comment: with jquery: `elem.innerHTML == $("<em>&mdash;</em>").html()`

Comment: `elem.innerHTML == document.createRange().createContextualFragment("&lt;").firstChild.textContent`

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev , that's pretty neat. You should consider adding it as an answer (with more explanation, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new DOM element, and compare the two:

```js
/**
 * Test that a DOM element's inner HTML is === &mdash;
 */
function mdashTest(el) {
    var tempEl = document.createElement('div');
    tempEl.innerHTML = '&mdash;';

    return el.innerHTML === tempEl.innerHTML;
}

// Test it!
elem = document.getElementById('dash');
alert( mdashTest( elem ) );
```

```html
<div id="dash">&mdash;</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The unicode equivalent of emdash is `\u2014`. You can use this unicode to compare with the html.

The default encoding for HTML meta is set to `UTF` so all the entities are converted to UTF-8. Read More https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#Attributes

```js
var dash = document.getElementById('dash').innerText;

alert(dash === '\u2014');
```

```html
<div id="dash">&mdash;</div>
```

Comment: Clever solution. However, I still want to use `&mdash;` in my code and not any other characters

Comment: @RichardWallace Try changing charset as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835821/reading-utf8-chars-using-innerhtml-returns-0xfffd-for-all-chars answer

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that:

1. through `DOMParser()`

```js
function parseToText(code) {
  return new DOMParser().parseFromString('<em>' + code + '</em>', "text/html").firstChild.textContent;
}
var is = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML == parseToText("&mdash;");
document.write("isEquals ", is, parseToText("&mdash;"));
```

```html
<em id="text">&mdash;</em>
```

2. Or, with jQuery:

```js
function parseToText(code) {
  return $("<em>" + code + "</em>").html()
}
var isEquals = document.getElementById('text').innerText == parseToText("&mdash;");
document.write("isEquals ", isEquals);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<em id="text">&mdash;</em>
```

3. Or, with plain JavaScript:

```js
function parseToText(code) {
  return document.createRange().createContextualFragment(code).firstChild.textContent;
}
var isEquals = document.getElementById('text').innerText == parseToText("&mdash;");
document.write("isEquals ", isEquals);
```

```html
<em id="text">&mdash;</em>
```