# How can get original content(with ascii codes) from element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, ascii

There is html code: `<p id="content">&mdash;<p>`.

**Output** should be `<p id="content">&mdash;<p>` or `&mdash;`.

I tried to get it below, but its result is only `—`?

```js
document.writeln("Output:");
document.writeln(document.getElementById("content").innerHTML);
document.writeln(document.getElementById("content").innerText);
document.writeln(document.getElementById("content").outerHTML);
document.writeln(document.getElementById("content").outerHTML);
document.writeln(document.getElementById("content").textContent);
```

```html
<p id="content">&mdash;<p>
```

How can achieve such as output through JavaScript (or framework)? Is it possible?

Comment: if html code was `<p id="content">&lt;<p>` i want to get `&lt;`(not `<`) through js code.

Comment: Sorry, I mean **dynimac content**: For example: `<div id="content">expression a &lt b  &mdash blah blah  ....</div>`. Then output should be `expression a &lt b  &mdash blah blah  ....` or with html contents as `String` ( console.log(), document.write(), it doesn't matter )

Comment: I just try to solve problem of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32801962/4365315 (i try to find fourth way for this issue)

Comment: I just want dynamic way, if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.  Here's an example, outputting to the console not the page.  You'll have to look at your console to see the output.
I follow this with an explanation.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test JS entity capture</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>
        From <em>"How can get original content(with ascii codes) from element?"</em><br>
        <code>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803029/</code>
        </p>

        <p id="targetP">
        This is <code>&amp;mdash;</code> : <span id="mdash">&mdash;</span>
        </p>
    </body>
    <script>
    var elm = document.getElementById('mdash');
    console.log('elm.innerHTML = ' + elm.innerHTML);
    console.log('elm.innerText = ' + elm.innerText);
    </script>
</html>
```

What happens?

The server sends the source HTML and, possibly separately, the javascript.
The browser parses the HTML and builds the DOM tree (Document Object Model).

When it parses the HTML, it turns the character entity reference `&mdash;` into the actual character the reference represents; now the DOM contains the character `—` and when you get either the `innerText` or `innerHTML` of that element using javascript you get the character.  You have no way to know whether that character was typed (like I typed it just now: shift+option+dash on a Mac) or if it was originally sent as a character entity.

Comment: Thanks, so it is inpossible

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't *easily* get the raw content of the element before it's rendered.  However, you *can* get the UTF-16 char code of the character.

```js
var content = document.getElementById("content").innerText;
var code = "&#" + content.charCodeAt(0) + ";";
var safeCode = code.replace("&", "&amp;");

//This prints the dash
document.writeln(code);

//This prints the raw code (&#8212;)
document.writeln("<br>" + safeCode);

//This will output &#8212; to the console
console.log(code);
```

```html
Original content: <span id="content">&mdash;<span><br>
```

This gives you [`&#8212;`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm) the UTF-16 code for `&mdash;`.

Comment: Yes it does...  Check the console (F12).

Comment: Thanks, @ScottKaye for efford. I want to be same with content. I compare output with somedata. see my last comments below of question

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with pure JavaScript but it's possible with some libraries like Underscore and jQuery. The jQuery's way is considered less secure (I don't know why), so, I am going to write the way to do it with Underscore.

You can do so with *Underscore* with `_.escape(string);`.

But when you will print it then the browser will render it. To overcome this problem you can split the returned string and then add a `<span>` element in between them.

See [the demo](http://jsbin.com/tisuwe/edit?html,js,console,output).

> This only works for `&`, `<`, `>`, `"`, and `.

Comment: I want to achieve `&lt;` (not `<`)

Comment: Ok, Arjun. there is some problem with console.log: http://jsbin.com/bexibepovo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev Updated my link for console.log also.  The underscore.js also escapes the `&`. That is why I have stored the first character which is `&` in `y[0]` and performing the `escape` on the other values of `y`. And at last I am joining them together.